# I have a subclass inheriting from a superclass and overriding a function. How do I get the output to come out as 3 and 6?

Tags: python, class, overriding, super

I've messed around with parameters and the classes in general, and I still can't get it to work. Even if I remove `self.v3`, which I need, I get `None` as the second output...

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
    def together(self):
        return self.v1 + self.v2

class Sub1(Base):
    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3):
        super(Sub1, self).__init__(v1, v2)
        self.v3 = v3
    def together(self):
        super(Sub1, self).together() + self.v3
b1 = Base(1,2)
print b1.together()
s1 = Sub1(3,2,1)
print s1.together()
```

Output: `3, 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclass's `together` method does not actually return the value. Change it to

```
return super(Sub1, self).together() + self.v3
```